# How can I change my hanoi tower output display vertically?

Tags: c++, towers-of-hanoi

I'm making hanoi tower for my assignment. I asked my professor to check my code before submitting it. My professor said he would give me a high score if I printed my display vertically, but I don't know how to change it to vertical. How can I change it to vertical? and also the towers are out in reverse, how can I get it back?

[image]

MyStack is in the header that the professor make it for us

```
struct MyStack{
int tos; //top of stack
char s[MAXSTACK]; //MAXSTACK is 100.
}
void createS(MyStack &S) {
    S.tos = -1;
}
void pushS(MyStack &S, char item) {
    S.s[++S.tos] = item;
}

char popS(MyStack& S) {
    return(S.s[S.tos--]);
}
bool isEmptyS(MyStack& S) {
    if (S.tos == -1)
        return (true);
    return false;
}
```

This is the main.

```
const static int TOWER_CNT=3;

void printTower(MyStack tower[TOWER_CNT]) {
    MyStack tempStack; // temporary stacks to temporarily store tower values
    createS(tempStack); // reset temporary stack
    char tempNum;
    cout << "                                                                                        ===============================" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < TOWER_CNT; i++) { // display all tower.
        cout << "                                                                                        Tower " << i + 1 << ": ";

        while (!isEmptyS(tower[i])) {
            pushS(tempStack, popS(tower[i])); // Put it upside down in a temporary stack because it has to be printed from the beginning of the tower.
        }
        while (!isEmptyS(tempStack)) { // Print out the value of the temporary stack and put it back into the tower.
            tempNum = popS(tempStack);
            //cout << (int)tempNum << " "; // print by number.
            //cout << "                                                                                                 ";
            change(tempNum); // change number into *
            cout << "\n                                                                                                 ";
            pushS(tower[i], tempNum);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "                                                                                        ===============================" << endl;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You may want to ask your instructor why a `createS` function in the stack rather than the usual constructor. The answer might be very interesting and educational.

Comment: At least as I'd normally expect to see things, the disks on each peg would be shown vertically, but the three pegs would be horizontal from each other.

Comment: One of the first steps of formatting output is visualizing what the output will look like. Could you (in a text editor) write out the expected output if you were able to print the display vertically? How do *you* want the output to appear for various possibilities of disks? *Hint: don't design for just a tower with disks 1, 2, and 3 as the design might be misleading. Also look at other possibilities, such as only disks 2 and 3.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve some global information from your towers.
then you might do:

```
int maxHeight(const MyStack (&towers)[TOWER_CNT])
{
    auto res = 0;
    for (const auto& tower : towers) {
        // Alternatively, you might take the sum, for fixed size towers.
        res = std::max(res, tower.tos + 1);
    }
    return res;
}

int baseWidth(const MyStack (&towers)[TOWER_CNT])
{
    auto res = 0;
    for (const auto& tower : towers) {
        auto base = ((tower.tos == -1) ? 1 : tower.s[0]);
        res = std::max(res, base);
    }
    return res;
}


void printTowers(const MyStack (&towers)[TOWER_CNT]) {
    auto height = maxHeight(towers);
    auto base = baseWidth(towers);

    for ([[maybe_unused]]const auto& _ : towers) {
            std::cout << std::string((base) / 2, ' ')
                      << std::string(1, '^')
                      << std::string((base - 1) / 2, ' ') << "   ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for ([[maybe_unused]]const auto& _ : towers) {
            std::cout << std::string((base) / 2, ' ')
                      << std::string(1, '|')
                      << std::string((base - 1) / 2, ' ') << "   ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j != height; ++j) {
        for (const auto& tower : towers) {
            auto plate_index = height - j - 1;
            auto count = ((plate_index < tower.tos + 1)
                         ? tower.s[plate_index] // You might use (2 * tower.s[plate_index] + 1)
                                                // For larger but better display.
                         : 0);

            // -1 there are to handle even count for display
            std::cout << std::string(base / 2 - count / 2, ' ')
                      << std::string(count / 2, '*')
                      << std::string(1, count == 1 ? '*' : '|')
                      << std::string((count - 1) / 2, '*')
                      << std::string((base - 1) / 2 - (count - 1) / 2, ' ') << "   ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    for ([[maybe_unused]]const auto& _ : towers) {
        std::cout << std::string(base, '=') << "   ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

With output similar to:

```
      ^               ^               ^         
      |               |               |         
     *|*              |               |         
   ***|***            *             **|**        
  ****|****      *****|*****    ******|******   
=============   =============   =============
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/TumEht)

That also handles even number, but display is not fine IMO.

Fill free to adapt to your look&feel.